# Finding all symbolic and hard links to a file on UNIX

Tags: unix, bash, symbolic-link, hardlink

If I have a specific file in a UNIX filesystem, is there a way to use bash to find all links to that file, both symbolic and hard?  If I need different commands for each, what are they?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this with GNU `find`:

```
find /start/dir -L -samefile /file/to/check -exec ls -li {} \;
```

Example output:

```
1234704 -rw-r--r-- 2 user1 user1 1134 2009-09-11 11:12 ./x1
1234704 -rw-r--r-- 2 user1 user1 1134 2009-09-11 11:12 ./x2
1234983 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1 2 2009-10-31 16:56 ./testx -> x1
2345059 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user2 user2 2 2010-01-03 16:17 ./x3 -> x1
```

You could use `-ls` instead of `-exec` but it will show the inode and other information of the target file instead of the individual files.

Comment: This output is showing hard and sym links? Sym links indicated by -> arrow?

Comment: @aaaidan: Yes, that's correct. The inode number of x1 and x2 are the same indicating that they are hard links. The arrow indicates a symlink. Using `-L` and `-samefile` causes both to be listed. If you omit `-L` then symbolic links are not followed (see `man find`).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have GNU Find you can do this:

```
find / -inum "$(ls -i /file/to/check | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
```

But it won't work for symbolic links.

Comment: Oh I see now that this question already answers this: http://superuser.com/questions/12972/to-see-hardlinks-by-ls