# How to find all symbolic links to a given file/directory?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

How can you find all symbolic links to a given file / directory?

This previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/90845/finding-all-symbolic-and-hard-links-to-a-file-on-unix) only applies to hardlinks (if I read correctly).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `find /dir -lname /link/target`. It searches link contents with shell pattern; e.g. you can use * and ? wildcards in target specification.

One drawback of this method is that it searches *contents* of links, not their *expanded paths*, so if you need to find relative links to absolute paths (if e.g. there are more than one file with same name) you need a more complicated script.

Also you can use other apporoach: `find -L /dir -samefile /link/target`. This causes `find` to dereference symlinks and after check the *dereferenced* path that is expanded by OS to be same as provided, so both relative and absolute links will be handled by Linux. This solves problem of previous method.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with busybox find?  It doesn't seem to have `-samefile` or `-lname`.

Comment: @g.rocket It's harder. You will need to use something like `find ... -exec sh -c 'stat -c %N | egrep '-> yourlink$'`, replacing `yourlink` with the link you're looking for. Also, much, much slower.