# Listing All Linked Files

Tags: linux, ln

I can't seem to find a way to do this, so maybe it's not actually possible, but I was wondering if there was a way to list all files that link to a file.

For example.

```
touch a
ln a b
ln a c
```

I want to find out what files link to a (not symlinks, mind you), assuming that this is more complicated (they are spread around to different directories).

I kind of understand about the filesystem storing links in one area and data in another, so I understand it probably takes more work to find a link from a file location than the other way around.

If I missed another question asking the same thing, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `find / -samefile /file/to/compare`.

There were a similar question: [Finding all symbolic and hard links to a file on UNIX](https://superuser.com/questions/90845/finding-all-symbolic-and-hard-links-to-a-file-on-unix)

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess I just wasn't searching for the correct thing. Thanks!

Comment: This only works with GNU Find.

Comment: I found no convenient options to do this in BSD Find, but you could try getting an inode number with `ls -i` and then doing `find /mountpoint -x -inum $INODE`. Inode represents contents of the file and not the filename.